# How to prove there is no natural deduction proof for $\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))\vdash\forall xP(x) \lor ∀xQ(x).$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

How to prove there is no natural deduction proof for
 $$\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))\vdash\forall xP(x) \lor ∀xQ(x).$$

I don't know how to prove this, maybe by semantic?

Comment: Just consider the case $P(x)=x$ is an even number and $Q(x)=x$ is an odd number.

Comment: What if $Q(x)$ is $\neg P(x)$?

Comment: @Leo163 Is this enough? What does "P(x) = x is an even number" mean?

Comment: What I mean is that if your deduction was correct, then it would hold in every theory. One example of this is usual arithmetic: $P(x)$ is the sentence stating that $x$ is even, and $Q(x)$ states that $x$ is odd. Now, it is true that every number is odd or even, but it is not true that every number is odd or every number is even.

Comment: I’ve got it. I can also say that P(x):“x is an apple.” and Q(x): “x is not an apple,” where x are fruits.